# Highscores aren't showing in guiTexts

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have recently made 2 new scripts with playerprefs for setting the score when player reaches the end of the level and i'm try to write them to the highscores menu by using get there, there was a freezing problem solved by imapler, but the score still isn't showing
Scriptname: ScoringPts...
Script for counting score:

```
var Score : int;

function Start(){
    gameObject.Find("TooLateGUI").guiTexture.enabled = false;
}
function TimerOfDeath(){
    if(Score == 0){
        gameObject.Find("TooLateGUI").guiTexture.enabled = true;
        gameObject.Find("Score").guiText.enabled = false;
        yield WaitForSeconds(5.0);
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
}

function Update () {
    Score -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    guiText.text = "Score: "+Score;
    TimerOfDeath();
}
```

Scriptname: HighScores...
set playerpref:

```
//run at start if score doesn't exist yet to initialise playerPref
function Start(){
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore"))
             PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore", 0);
}


//run when level is completed
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        Score = gameObject.Find("ScoreCount").GetComponent("ScoringPts").Update("Score");
        if(Score > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore", Score);
        }
    }
}
```

scriptname: GetHighScores...
get playerpref:

```
      #pragma strict

function Start () {
var hscount = 1;
var iterations = 1;
var maxIterations = 5;
var findtext = gameObject.Find("scoreLevel"+(hscount));
while(hscount < 5 && iterations > maxIterations){
if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Level"+(hscount)+"HighScore")){
findtext.guiText.text = "Level"+(hscount)+ ": " + PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level"+(hscount)+"HighScore");
hscount++;
}
iterations++;
}
}
```

no build errors but could it be that i'm using the playerprefs wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
while(hscount < 5){
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Level"+(hscount)+"HighScore")){
         var findtext = gameObject.Find("scoreLevel"+(hscount));
        findtext.guiText.text = "Level"+(hscount)+ ": " + PlayerPrefs.GetFloat((hscount)+"HighScore");
        hscount++;
    }
}
```

The game doesn't enter the if 5 times which will cause a infinite loop. Most likely it is because of

```
if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore"))
             PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Application.loadedLevelName+"HighScore", 0);
```

The pref is only set the first time you load the level. Which means the first 4 levels wont have 5 entries in the pref.

Try setting some additional condition on the while to make sure it exits like

```
while(hscount < 5 && iterations < maxIterations){
    if(...){
        hscount++;
    }
    iterations++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
i tried this code but it's still freezing, i'l update my question with the additional condition.

Comment: My mistake, its supposed to be && not ||, i will update the awnser. Also < not >.

Comment: it stopped freezing i'l update the question but i'l already accept your answer since you solved the freezing but if you have an idea why the guiTexts aren't showing the score feel free to update again thanks a lot!!!